# funcion ajax que devuelva un valor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
function appelTeams(team, ligue)
{
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: team,
        dataType: 'json',
        headers: {"X-AUTH-TOKEN" : 'f6b3ae25342242f8b76a233c4c781686'},
        success: function(teams) {
            $("#ligue").empty();
            $("#teams").empty();
            $("#teamSel").empty();
            $("#players").empty();

            //console.log (teams.teams);

            //Ligue SELECTIONE de l'API
            $("#ligue").text(ligue);
            for (var e =0; e < teams.count; e++)
            {

                //console.log(e+teams.teams[e].crestUrl);
                if (imgServer(teams.teams[e].crestUrl)==2) {
                    console.log("Holi");
                }

                //Chaque equipe a ses Joueurs
                $("#teams").append("<div class='col-md-3' id = 'team"+e+"' onclick=\"appelPlayers('"+teams.teams[e]._links.players.href+"', '"+teams.teams[e].name+"')\"><img id='img' src='"+teams.teams[e].crestUrl+"'><div><h1>"+teams.teams[e].name+"</h1></div></div>");
                //$("#logo").attr('src',teams.teams[e].crestUrl);
            }

        }
    });
}
```

y quiero llamar a la funcion para verficar si la url de la imagen funciona

```
function imgServer(img){
    var res;
    $.ajax({
        url: img,
    success: function(data) {
            res=1
    },
    error: function() {
        res=2;
    }
   });
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas hacer una petición ajax por cada imagen para saber si encuentra o no la imagen. Si la petición tira error usar en cambio una imagen por defecto;

[Basándote en la documentación](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) lo siguiente funciona, aunque es un ejemplo burdo que eventualmente podría saturar las llamadas si tienes muchos equipos.

```
for (var e =0; e < teams.count; e++) {

    var crestUrl = teams.teams[e].crestUrl;

    $.get( crestUrl )
     .done(function() {
        // imagen existe 
        $("#teams").append(....);
     })
     .fail(function() {
        // imagen no existe 
        crestUrl = 'img_en_blanco.jpg';
        $("#teams").append(....);
     });
}
```